# Troubles with setting MultiSelectList from code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing a simple asp.net mvc application, but I am having problems with pre-selecting items inside multi select list. Here is my code inside controller:

```
 ViewBag.Authors = new MultiSelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorId", "FullName", db.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookId == id)).Select(a => a.AuthorId));
```

and here is the razor code inside view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorIds, "Authors")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AuthorIds, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Authors)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorIds)
</div>
```

It renders the multi select list, but it doesn't select items I set in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the code in which you preselect the items.

Comment: It's in the controller code above (ViewBag.Authors).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a little late to be answering this, but it *should* work to pre-fill model.AuthorIds (in the controller) to the values you want to be selected in the view. The method where you set the selected values on the SelectList is really for use with the non-strongly-typed Html.ListBox, not the strongly-typed Html.ListBoxFor.